# API request WaitingForActivation "Not yet computed" error via asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

this is my code  via asp.net web form:

```
public string GetAccessToken()
    {
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue=true;

        string accessToken = "";
      
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol=System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptLanguage.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("en_US"));

          

            var clientId = "<"+PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID+">";
            var clientSecret = "<"+PAYPAL_SECRET_KEY+">";
            var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clientId+":"+clientSecret);



            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization=new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(bytes));

            var keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

            keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"));

            var responseMessage = client.PostAsync("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token", new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues));

            accessToken= responseMessage.Status.ToString();
        }

       
        return accessToken;
    }
```

But I get this error:

Id = 9, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"  in AccessToken

Answer (score 2):

client.PostAsync is an asynchronous method that returns a Task object. You either need to [await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) it (this is the preferred approach), but that would require a change to the signature of the  GetAccessToken() function (and probably to the upstream code) or simply do the following:

```
var responseTask = client.PostAsync("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token", new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues));
responseTask.Wait();
var responseMessage = responseTask.Result;
```

Comment: Using `Wait()` with no argument like this is equivalent to what `.Result` already does internally so is superfluous in this case. It is, however, probably a good idea to use one of the timeout overloads of `Wait` such as [`Wait(TimeSpan)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?view=net-6.0#system-threading-tasks-task-wait(system-timespan)) so that the thread won't be blocked indefinitely but will error out in the event of the server not responding.

Comment: Response is : {StatusCode: 406, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Acceptable', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Connection: keep-alive
  Paypal-Debug-Id: fc7c44a7458fe
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
  Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache, max-age=0
  Date: Sun, 27 Mar 2022 09:33:51 GMT
  Content-Length: 184
  Content-Type: application/json
}}

Comment: after used responseTask.Wait(); , responseMessage.StatusCode is : NotAcceptable

Comment: This means everything works, but the request you're sending to the API is malformed. Check the documentation for the API you're invoking and make sure you construct a proper request.